# Cross Entropy Loss for One Hot Encoding

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation, loss-function, one-hot-encoding, cross-entropy

CE-loss sums up the loss over all output nodes

Sum_i[ - target_i*log(output_i) ].

The derivative of CE-loss is: - target_i/output_i.

Since for a target=0 the loss and derivative of the loss is zero regardless of the actual output, it seems like only the node with target=1 recieves feedback on how to adjust weights.

I also noticed the singularity in the derivative for output=0. How is this processed during backpropagation?

I do not see how the weights are adjusted to match the target=0. Maybe you know better :)

Comment: Your formula is incomplete, see [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/260505/machine-learning-should-i-use-a-categorical-cross-entropy-or-binary-cross-entro) and [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9302/the-cross-entropy-error-function-in-neural-networks).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the formula you mentioned if your final layer forms a probability distribution (that way all nodes will receive feedback since when one final layer neuron's output increases, others have to decrease because they form a probability distribution and must add up to 1). You can achieve having final layer forming a probability distribution by applying softmax activation function to final layer. You can read more about it [here](https://deepnotes.io/softmax-crossentropy).